# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices not str

Tags: python, tkinter

I cant get this to work, I have read other SO qs regarding this issue but I cant seem to find the info to suit my application. Im getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices not str`
Im holding my `with open` in a function as I only want to call it when a button is pressed. Im sure it has to do with `for row in csv_file:` do I need a `for line in csv_file:` then `for row`? Im stuck

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageTk
    import csv
    from tkinter import filedialog
        def select_input_file():
            input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
            with open(input_file_path) as csv_file:
                csv_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
                 for row in csv_file:
                 RoNumber = row['Ro Number']
                 DateIn = row['Date In']
                 TimeIn = row['Time In']
                 TimeOut = row['Time Out']
                 RegoNumber = row['Rego Number']
                 CustomerName = row['Customer Name']
                 VehicleMake = row['Vehicle Make']
                 VehicleModel = row['Vehicle Model']
                 JobDescription = row['Job Description']
                 CurrentStatus = row['Current Status']
        
            treetime.insert("", 0, values=(RoNumber, DateIn, TimeIn, TimeOut, RegoNumber,
                                           CustomerName, VehicleMake, VehicleModel, JobDescription, CurrentStatus))

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error `RoNumber  = row['Ro Number']`

Here is some .csv

```
'Ro Number,Date In,Rego Number,Customer Name,Vehicle Make,Vehicle Model,Job Description,Current Status,Time In,Time Out
123456,6/07/2020,abc123,Conor McGregor,Hyundai ,i30,"15,000 Km Service",,8:00:00 AM,4:00:00 PM
654321,31/07/2020,acb321,Nate Diaz,Ferrari,Enzo,Crank but wont fire,,9:30:00 AM,4:45:00 PM
123456,6/07/2020,abc123,Conor McGregor,Hyundai ,i30,"15,000 Km Service",,8:00:00 AM,4:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code.  It seems `treetime.insert(...)` is the same level of `with ...`, therefore it will be executed once and not for each record read from file.

Comment: this fixed it.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the row columns by field name, not index. To use field names, try the `DictReader` function.

```
csv_file = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

You're also reusing a variable name which may be causing issues.

Replace this code:

```
with open(input_file_path) as csv_file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_file:
```

With this:

```
with open(input_file_path) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
```

This code works for me (it also works using a csv file):

```
from io import StringIO

scsv = '''
Ro Number,Date In,Rego Number,Customer Name,Vehicle Make,Vehicle Model,Job Description,Current Status,Time In,Time Out
123456,6/07/2020,abc123,Conor McGregor,Hyundai ,i30,"15,000 Km Service",,8:00:00 AM,4:00:00 PM
654321,31/07/2020,acb321,Nate Diaz,Ferrari,Enzo,Crank but wont fire,,9:30:00 AM,4:45:00 PM
123456,6/07/2020,abc123,Conor McGregor,Hyundai ,i30,"15,000 Km Service",,8:00:00 AM,4:00:00 PM
'''.strip()

f = StringIO(scsv)
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for row in reader:
         RoNumber = row['Ro Number']
         DateIn = row['Date In']
         TimeIn = row['Time In']
         TimeOut = row['Time Out']
         RegoNumber = row['Rego Number']
         CustomerName = row['Customer Name']
         VehicleMake = row['Vehicle Make']
         VehicleModel = row['Vehicle Model']
         JobDescription = row['Job Description']
         CurrentStatus = row['Current Status']
         
         print(RoNumber,DateIn,TimeIn,TimeOut)
```

Output:

```
123456 6/07/2020 8:00:00 AM 4:00:00 PM
654321 31/07/2020 9:30:00 AM 4:45:00 PM
123456 6/07/2020 8:00:00 AM 4:00:00 PM
```

Here is the code using tkinter. It works correctly with the sample data.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageTk
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog

def select_input_file(x):
  input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
  with open(input_file_path) as csv_file:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in rdr:
          RoNumber = row['Ro Number']
          DateIn = row['Date In']
          TimeIn = row['Time In']
          TimeOut = row['Time Out']
          RegoNumber = row['Rego Number']
          CustomerName = row['Customer Name']
          VehicleMake = row['Vehicle Make']
          VehicleModel = row['Vehicle Model']
          JobDescription = row['Job Description']
          CurrentStatus = row['Current Status']

          print(RoNumber,DateIn,TimeIn,TimeOut)

widget = Button(None, text='Open CSV')
widget.pack()
widget.bind('<Button-1>', select_input_file)
widget.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
123456 6/07/2020 8:00:00 AM 4:00:00 PM
654321 31/07/2020 9:30:00 AM 4:45:00 PM
123456 6/07/2020 8:00:00 AM 4:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I have tried `csv_file = csv.DictReader(csv_file)` but this only returns the first line of the `.csv `

Comment: Change the variable as mentioned. If that does not help, please post part of the csv file so I can test. Also - Which line is causing the error? Can you show the traceback?

Comment: I tried the code using the `DictReader`. It seemed to work correctly.

Comment: thanks Mike, still only reading 1 line from `.csv`. My code is stored within a function perhaps this is the reason?

Comment: Did you change the variable name?